# How to sign self-compiled Qt dll?

Tags: qt, certificate

Dlls in Qt official prebuilt are signed with Qt official certificate, but I compiled Qt opensource myself, I'm wondering how can I sign these self-compiled dlls, is it legal to sign these dlls with my own certificate and distribute them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can obtain a code signing certificate from a certificate authority (which will cost you a bit of cash, but it's not too bad) and then sign your custom compiled files with that certificate.
As far as I know that's perfectly legal (but I'm not a lawyer, so don't take my word for it - ask a real lawyer if it's important to you).